# Getting an error while debugging in VSCode (Windows)

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

```
'${fileDirname}' can not be resolved. Please open an editor
[Open launch.json] [Cancel]
```

I m getting this error whenever I try to debug my program in VSCode.
I checked my launch.json file, everything seems fine.

```json
    "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "(gdb) Launch",
          "type": "cppdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
          "args": [],
          "stopAtEntry": false,
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "environment": [],
          "externalConsole": false,
          "MIMode": "gdb",
          "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
          "setupCommands": [
            {
              "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
              "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
              "ignoreFailures": true
            }
          ],
          "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
      ]
```

Comment: place the focus in the C/C++ file you want to run and press F5, have you saved the file, are you using a workspace (File | Open Folder)

Comment: I'm new to VSCode so don't know what workspace is, I just opened my file from a folder and yeah saved the file.

Comment: `(File | Open Folder)` is a menu option to try

Comment: Also, in the terminal it is showing, `activate does not accept more than one argument:
['C:\\Users\\DELL\\anaconda3', '/d', '/c', 'C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe', '-g', 'e:\\CPP\\codeforces.cpp', '-o', 'e:\\CPP\\codeforces.exe']`

Comment: Did U solve this? I have same issue.